# Characterization of absolute value : how to tackle such problems?

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value

In a problem we are asked to show that there existe a unique function $\alpha:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that :

- $\alpha(x)=x$ for all real $x\geq0$
- $\alpha(zw)=\alpha(z)\alpha(w)$ for all $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$
- $\alpha$ is bounded on the unit circle $C(0,1)$

My question is : considering that the characterization of the absolute value is only hinted in the title, how would you tackle this problem ?
Would you just prove that $\alpha(z) = |z|$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $\alpha (z) = |z|$ does work, so let's set about proving that this is unique.

Consider any $e^{i \theta}$. We claim that $\alpha(e^{i\theta}) = \pm 1$. If not, then note $\alpha(e^{i n \theta}) = \alpha(e^{i \theta})^n$ for all integers; taking a very positive or negative $n$ will yield $\alpha(e^{i \theta})^n$ unbounded and hence $\alpha(e^{i n \theta})$, contradicting the boundedness condition.

Note that $\alpha(e^{i \theta}) = -1$ is impossible, since $\alpha(e^{i\theta/2})^2 = \alpha(e^{i \theta}) = -1$, but a real cannot square to $-1$.

So we conclude that $\alpha(e^{i \theta}) = 1$ for all $\theta$, and hence $\alpha(re^{i\theta}) = \alpha(r) \alpha(e^{i \theta}) = r$ for all reals $r \geq 0$, giving the desired answer (by taking $r = |z|$, $\theta = \arg(z)$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But where did you prove that $\alpha$ is unique ? Should we do that or the fact that we identify $\alpha$ with the absolute value is enough ?

Comment: @AlanSimonin The answer proves that by necessity $\alpha(re^{i\theta})=r$, and since each complex number $z$ can be written as $z=re^{i\theta}$ and then $|z|=r$, this proves that $\alpha$ must the absolute value function.

Comment: @AlanSimonin I've shown that if such an $\alpha$ exists, then $\alpha(re^{i \theta}$ must be $r$, which means the only $\alpha$ that could be a solution is the absolute value function. It's straightforward to verify this works, so we indeed have that $\alpha$ is unique.

Comment: @hdighfan I see, thanks for the clarification !